# React/Redux calls for a row of cards

Tags: reactjs, api, asynchronous, redux

I am creating a row of 10 cards. Each card needs to make its own call to an API to get a rendition url. How would I be able to achieve that with React/Redux?

Below is my React Card component. I am looping through this component 10 times, each time with a different `cardId` which the card uses to call the API to fetch the image url.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {fetchRendition} from '../../../actions/RenditionAction';


class Card extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
      // action call to fetch rendition for card
      this.props.fetchRendition(this.props.cardId);
    }


    render() {
       return (
          <div className='card'>
             <div className='card-image-container'>
                <div className='card-image' style = {{backgroundImage: `url(${this.props.rendition.url})`}}/>
            </div>
         </div>
      );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {rendition: state.card} 
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchRendition})(Card);
```

Looping through this card component looks like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

 class RowOfCards extends Component {

    render() {
      const ArrayOfIds = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4','id5', 'id6', 'id7', 'id8'. 'id9', 'id10']
      return ArrayOfIds.map((id) => <Card cardId = {id}/>))
   }
}

export default RowOfCards;
```

Right now with this implementation, all 10 cards end up with the same image. The expected behavior is that each card should have a different image. How do I get the cards to update with its own image after each card makes the call to the API?

Comment: where is the code of the loop to render all of 10 cards? can you add that as well?

Comment: @mindaJalaj I updated with an example of the loop

Comment: can you also share the code for fetchRendition? whatever you have moentioned till now seems correct, for every cardid fetchRendition, now the way you are storing the response of this matters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be replacing the fetched image in the reducer with the updated one and since you only have one `rendition` image in your reducer, all cards use the same one.

For your usecase, it seems that there is not need of redux, what you need is to store the image in the Card component state, nobody except the Card component knows about its own image.

```
export default class Card extends Component {
    state = {
      rendition: {}
    }
    componentDidMount() {
      // action call to fetch rendition for card
      fetchRendition(this.props.cardId).then((res) => {  // make an api call and store the response in state and not in redux store
        this.setState({rendition: res})
      });
    }


    render() {
       return (
          <div className='card'>
             <div className='card-image-container'>
                <div className='card-image' style = {{backgroundImage: `url(${this.state.rendition.url})`}}/>
            </div>
         </div>
      );
    }
}
```

The Author of Redux @dan_abramov, wrote an article on [`You might not need redux`](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367). Please have a look at it

Comment: Glad it helped, do go through the article by @dan_abramov.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your codes, it seems like you're only storing a single "card" object in your reducer. You should store it as an array of "card" objects instead.

I am assuming your reducer looks something like this

```
const card = (state = null, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'STORE_CARD':
      return {
        action.payload.data
      },
    ...
  }
}
```

If the above is true, each action will overwrite the card object. Instead, store the card object data as an object list with cardId as the key as such:

```
const cards = (state = null, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'STORE_CARDS':
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.payload.data.cardId]: action.payload.data
      },
    ...
  }
}
```

Then, in your component:

```
render() {
   return (
      <div className='card'>
         <div className='card-image-container'>
            <div className='card-image' style = {{backgroundImage: `url(${this.props.rendition[this.props.cardId].url})`}}/>
        </div>
     </div>
  );
}
```